# Can't sign up for Google API key?

Tags: google-api

I'm trying to sign-up for a Google Libraries API Key at http://code.google.com/apis/loader/signup.html, but when I click
on "Sign-up for an API key," it keeps saying "The requested URL /apis/loader/signup.html was not found on this server."

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE: the sign-up link is working now**

Thanks for reporting the broken link, I asked the Google Libraries API team to fix it.

I'll let you know the correct link as soon as possible.